# DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating InvoiceSellsController

Tags: asp.net, .net, nopcommerce

I am trying to build a web App on top of nopcommerce, when I open (http://localhost:15536/invoicesells), it gives me the exception below, I think that the problem is in program.cs file with dependency injection, how should I deal with it?

```
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Nop.Web.Controllers.InvoiceSellsController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Nop.Web.Models.testContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Nop.Web.Models.testContext)'.

DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Nop.Web.Controllers.InvoiceSellsController.
```

- Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

    builder.ConfigureServices(
        services =>
            services.AddDbContext<testContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer("Server=HP\\KARIM;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true")));
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

- The controller

```
public class InvoiceSellsController : Controller
{
    private readonly testContext _context;

    public InvoiceSellsController(testContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

- The class that inherits from DbContext

```
public partial class testContext : DbContext
{
    public testContext()
    {
    }

    public testContext(DbContextOptions<testContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does nopCommerce come to play? Are you adding these classes to your cloned nopCommerce source?

Comment: That is done in the NopStartup class ... [nopCommerce Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/tutorials/inversion-of-control.html)